# Which type of app can I publish to Office Store?

Tags: development, 2013, sharepoint-addin

I want to know that which type of Apps I can add in Office Store for selling purpose?
I created an `AutoHosted App` and add it to Office Store and after few days I got the error report saying that `AutoHosted Apps` are not supported in Office Store.

I am now confuse because in every article of **MSDN** they have said that you can publish your app to Office Store **(But not mentioned that which type of app)**. For `AutoHosted App` they have said that you can publish your apps to Azure. And Now when I read this ***http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220035.aspx*** in that I see that AutoHosted apps are not currently available for Office store.

So which type of App can I now develop for Office Store ?
 1)`SharePoint Hosted app`
 2)`Provider Hosted App`?

Comment: I think too that's a Bit confused :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will work, but you can not use features with a wider scope than web. Follow this Msdn guide for taking the necessary step to publish apps from Visual Studio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220044.aspx

Comment: Thank you sir for the Answer. But there's a small confusion regarding `Provider Hosted App` that what will I publish when My App is created and in Seller Dashboard I need to put `.app` file. But in provider hosted app the app file do not contain all the project docs. as Autohosted and SharePoint hosted app both published the create only one .App that I can put on Seller Dashboard. but what about Provider Hosted.

Comment: Since the provider hosted app is made up by both an app, and a separate project containing the logic. This logic should not be hosted by the app user, but by you as provider. Hence this will mot be uploaded to the market place. This hosting is what is refered to as the web application in the link above, in relation to the provider hosted apps

Comment: So that I can't put a Provider Hosted App in the Seller Dashboard Account at the Time of new Creating new App for Office Store..?

Comment: Yes you can, but you are responsible for the hosting of the app webs so you need to give the address of the webapplication that will work as the hosting for the app webs