# How to publish provider hosted app to office store?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, publishing, apps-development

I have created the `Provider Hosted app` on my DEV machine. I completed the app.

But now I want to know that how can I publish my app to Office Store.

When I publish my App from Visual Studio it generated the `.app` file and also other files like one Batch file and some `.xml` files.

When we publish the `AutoHosted Apps` and `SharePoint Hosted Apps` both create only an `.app` file so we can easily put that file on seller dashboard at the time of publishing it for sell.

Now How can I publish the Provider Hosted App...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the link I have already provided to you [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71757/which-type-of-app-can-i-publish-to-office-store/71874#71874):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220044.aspx

Comment: Thank you sir. But I am not finding the proper steps. To publish my App to Office Store. So can you please provide me the steps that how to publish it. Or how to make the single .app that can be publish to Office Store.

Comment: A provider hosted app will contain of more than the .app file, as I have told you before. The rest is a solution package that need to be published on an separate webapplication, hosted by you. This webapplication address is added in the publishing process to the Marketplace