# Creating an app package to publish to the Store

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I'm preparing to publish my first SharePoint Hosted app to the Office Store but it requires a format of .xap, .appx, .appxbundle, .appxupload

Only an .app file is packaged when I click Publish in Visual Studio. Which of the above files should I create and what are the steps to do so?

Comment: Are you sure you're uploading to the Office Store and not the Windows Store? Office Store is actually called Office Marketplace and the Seller Dashboard is where you manage the Office Apps.

Comment: Yes, I'm in the Sellers Dashboard. There was only the Office option and the Azure option and I chose the former

Comment: .aapx ..xap etc are required for windows app. not sure where you are exactly publishing your app

Comment: you need to publish at the SharePoint store. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220033.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are visiting the windows app store as .appx,.xap etc are extentions for windows app.

See the detail steps to publish sharePoint hosted apps to office store at 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220044.aspx

Comment: this short answers by moderators are fine?http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71757/which-type-of-app-can-i-publish-to-office-store